Linking inputs cells to a certain arrangement of a Filter function List
I am using a FILTER formula to get a list of names from a Schedule (Subjected to changes throughout the month).
The thing is if for example I had two people at cells A1 and A2 scheduled to work on Saturday, Filter function will show an array for A1 and A3 according my criteria -Saturday- then if someone else had been signed up for Saturday and his name was written at Cell A2 the Array will change to be A1, A2 and A3 While if I had any human made inputs relevant to A1 and A3 guys in the output table, The inputs will remain in place while the array changes. Check the photo for a better clarification, please!
Thank you in advance for any tips and reading this issue!


Excel 2007 or 2010 don't have FILTER(). Tagging them both is wrong. Also it's better to post data as data, then as image. https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

To answer your question if it's possible to have the dynamic calculation result keep the order of it's output depending on the input values: no, unless input 1 or 2 can be linked to the data lines by certain logic (which seems to not be the case). You'd either need VBA, or enter the entries in column S and T behind the names in your data list above. You may want to reformat the way you log things for better visibility. How about something like: https://i.sstatic.net/vT3yNQo7.jpg

@P.b I appreciate a lot your recommendations but the inputs are more than just 2 inputs, I only simplified the issue Inputs ~ 13 must be categorized based on day date and name not just the name of the person so Grouped according to a monthly output table daily then each person will be assigned his inputs.

@P.b I wouldn't mind to go for a VBA if it will be running automatically for the inputs but still, I don't know which logic it could be. I even considered using the insert rows formula but it just adds new rows and the output table make excessively increase then also used the index and offset but it didn't work too>

If the top data is all data, not calculation, wouldn't my suggested layout be easier to read and it would not require calculations either (you may want conditional formatting on the input columns where date column contains Yes and the input columns are still blank where the top row's Day equals an input value, like in your own example

This is a rough setup of what I mean: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhxknrNHLDPCgZA6CU8BGwpqxeWXwg?e=TKJO46&nav=MTVfe0I3ODhBQjRCLUE4MjAtMkU0MS04QkNELTJBNkVGREY3QzBCRX0

@P.b I see. I believe I need a bit more explanation about your approach. I think conditional formatting can somehow help with locating there data are but I don't think I can go without having the name list, Department and Supervisors columns not automatically generated.

You mean B2, C2 and down? You can keep the calculation as you have it now.
